# What is the necessary condition for two vector set be aligned by an orthogonal matrix?

Tags: math, rotation, orthogonal

Suppose there are two vector sets $A$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{f \times 3}$

If there is an orthogonal matrix $R \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$ can align there two vector set perfectly,  e.g. $RA = B$

What is the necessary condition for A and B to satisfy that?

I know the orthogonal matrix can be solved by orthogonal procrustes algorithm, but that only gives the solution. I want to know the condition for A and B to make them be perfectly aligned by the $R$.

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting question, but off topic for SO, and suitable for math.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The necessary and sufficient condition is that

```
A'*A = B'*B
```

Unfortunately I've not been able to find a reference for this. Here, though is an outline of a proof.
We work inductively on the number of rows.

If this is 1 then each of A and B are column vectors, and the condition reads

```
A[i]*A[j] = B[i]*B[j] for all i,j
```

When i=j, this implies that |A[i]| = |B[i]| and so there are s[i] (each +-1) with

```
B[i] = s[i]*A[i]
```

If both A[i] and A[j] are non zero (then so are both B[i] and B[j]) we see

```
s[i]*s[j] = 1, so s[i] = s[j]
```

Since we can choose s[i] arbitrarily when A[i] (hence B[i]) is zero, it follows that we can choose all the s[i] to be the same so that B = s*A, as required

If the number of rows is greater than 1, write

```
A = (a A1) 
B = (b B1)
```

(where a is the first column of A, etc)

Note

```
A'*A = ( a'*a   a'*A1)
       ( A1'*a  A1'*A1)
```

and similarly for B.
If a is zero, so too is b, and

```
U*a = U*b for any U.
```

Thus we can assume a != 0 (and so b != 0).
if l is the length of a (and of b) we can find orthogonal U and V so that

```
U*a = l*e1
V*b = l*e1
```

(where e1 is (1,0,..0)')
Let

```
U*A = (l*e1 A2)
V*B = (l*e1 B2)
```

In terms of these we have

```
A'*A = (U*A)'*(U*A) = (l*l      l*e1'*A2)
                      (l*A2'*e1 A2'*A2  )
```

and similarly for B. Note that e1'*A2 is the first row of A2, so our condition implies that the first rows of A2 and B2 are the same.
If we write

```
A2 = ( x )
     ( A3)
```

(and similarly for B2) then

```
A2'*A2 = x'*x + A3'*A3 = x'*x + B3'*B3
```

So, by induction, there is a orthogonal Q with

```
B3 = Q*A3
```

But this implies

```
B2 = (1 0 ) * A2
     (0 Q )
```

and, unraveling the definitions, that there is an orthogonal W with

```
B = W*A
```